# What is IIS 6.0 doing with slashes after the page name in a URL?

Tags: asp.net, url, iis-6

Had a question from a client which stumped me.

They are using IIS 6.0 and for some reason, instead of making a normal request for a page on their server which I'll call www.domain.com/Default.aspx someone typed www.domain.com/Default.aspx/randomstuff

It seems that IIS's response was to serve Default.aspx as normal, but, as far as the browser is concerned, the path is www.domain.com/Default.aspx/ rather than www.domain.com/ and thus all relative paths to CSS, images, etc. fail

I looked at the traffic in Fiddler, and it seems that all of those image etc. requests, such as www.domain.com/Default.aspx/images/image.gif are ALSO returning the contents of Default.aspx, needless to say, not a valid image!

I don't believe they are doing anything special with URL rewriting, but just to be sure, I tried an experiment on a freshly created ASP.NET web application and the results were the same.

So what is causing IIS to pass a URL like /Default.aspx/randomstuff to the ASP.NET pipeline as a request for Default.aspx? And can it be stopped, and made to just throw a 404 as you'd expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the [PathInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.pathinfo.aspx) component.

You can stop like this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.PathInfo)) throw new HttpException(404);
```

Comment: Also see the comment regarding "Check that file exists" in IIS at the bottom of the MSDN article.

Comment: Seems that the best overload is `HttpException(404, "Not found")`. In addition, in my scenario, it was better to `Response.StatusCode = 404; Response.End();` instead of throwing an `HttpException`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's perfectly normal. Apache will do it too.

You can use it for routing, so you can have the URL `/script.name/random/stuff` instead of `/script.name?page=random&section=stuff` without having to set up URL rewriting.

Naturally the browser doesn't know that `script.name` is the real script, that `random` and `stuff` aren't really part of the path at the server-side. So all URLs will be relative to the `random` directory. Normally when you are writing an application with routing, you have to make sure you use rooted or absolute URLs through rather than relative URLs, for this reason.

> And can it be stopped, and made to just throw a 404 as you'd expect?

Yes, as in SLaks's answer. However it would probably be better to send a 301 to the real address without the trailing Path Info parts.